# How can I convert Python String to raw_value or Object value?

Tags: python

I am creating pages in Scribus via scripting to place text and images.
I wish to use pyexviv2 to read/write Exif XPKeywords. Reading from is fine by using 'human_value' to convert from the byte values returned. I realise I do not need to convert except to see that it worked.
I am splitting the obtained string from one tag and wish to write one part to another tag.
I understand that I cannot use 'human_value' in reverse (read only).
Can somebody point me in the right direction please? Below, progress so far, obtaining the 5th part of the filename, which works fine.

[EDIT] Adding... metadata['Exif.Image.XPKeywords']=parts[4] to write gives ValueError: Invalid Value.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import scribus #will test that Scribus is running
import pyexiv2
import string

metadata = pyexiv2.ImageMetadata('j:/BOOK/Banns/1.jpg')
metadata.read()

metadata.exif_keys
['Exif.Image.ImageDescription',
 'Exif.Image.DocumentName',
 'Exif.Image.XPComment',
 'Exif.Image.XPAuthor',
 'Exif.Image.XPSubject',
 'Exif.Image.XPKeywords',
 'Exif.Image.DateTime',
 'Exif.Image.Artist',
 'Exif.Image.Copyright',
 'Exif.Image.ExifTag']

tag=metadata['Exif.Image.DocumentName']
txt=tag.human_value
scribus.messageBox("", txt)     #instead of raw_value or just value
parts=txt.split(',',5)         #Split filename at ',' i.e. 5 strings in a List
scribus.messageBox("",parts[4]) #Separate Place from List
```

Answer (score 1):

After 4 hours research I have through trial and error found a working answer which may be useful to others.

I added to the question...
"metadata['Exif.Image.XPKeywords']=parts[4]" to write gives ValueError: Invalid Value
The answer is as follows because XPKeywords is utf-16...

```
metadata['Exif.Image.XPKeywords']=pyexiv2.utils.string_to_undefined(parts[4].encode('utf-16'))
metadata.write()
```